# Efficient way to get/remove first element from the list?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, linked-list

I want to take out and remove first element from the List. I can see, I have two options:

**First Approach:**

```
LinkedList<String> servers = new LinkedList<String>();
....
String firstServerName = servers.removeFirst();
```

**Second Approach**

```
ArrayList<String> servers = new ArrayList<String>();
....
String firstServerName = servers.remove(0);
```

I have lot of elements in my list.

- Is there any preference which one we should use?
- And what is the difference between the above two? Are they technically same thing in terms of performance? What is the complexity involve here if we have lot of elements?

What is the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: a) Define performance. There are many variables to measure for, such as time, efficiency, memory usage, etc. b) Write some testing code, using stopwatches (class, not physicals) and things of that nature to benchmark it and find out.

Comment: "What is the most efficient way to do this?" Depends on your scenario.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist

Answer (score 6):

If the comparison for "remove first" is between the `ArrayList` and the `LinkedList` classes, the `LinkedList` wins clearly.

Removing an element from a linked list costs `O(1)`, while doing so for an array (array list) costs `O(n)`.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `LinkedList`.

***Background:***

In practical terms, `LinkedList#removeFirst` is more efficient since it's operating over a doubly-linked list and the removal of first element basically consist in only unlinking it from the head of the list and update the next element to be the first one (complexity `O(1)`):

```
private E unlinkFirst(Node<E> f) {
    // assert f == first && f != null;
    final E element = f.item;
    final Node<E> next = f.next;
    f.item = null;
    f.next = null; // help GC
    first = next;
    if (next == null)
        last = null;
    else
        next.prev = null;
    size--;
    modCount++;
    return element;
}
```

`ArrayList#remove` is operating over an internal array structure which requires moving all subsequent elements one position to the left by copying over the subarray (complexity `O(n)`):

```
public E remove(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    modCount++;
    E oldValue = elementData(index);

    int numMoved = size - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0)
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                         numMoved);
    elementData[--size] = null; // clear to let GC do its work

    return oldValue;
}
```

***Additional answer:***

On the other hand, `LinkedList#get` operation requires traversing half of the entire list for retrieving an element at a specified index - in worst case scenario. `ArrayList#get` would directly access the element at the specified index since it's operating over an array.

My rule of thumbs for efficiency here would be:

- Use `LinkedList` if you do a lot of `add`/`remove` in comparison with
  access operations (e.g.: `get`);
- Use `ArrayList` if you do a lot
  of access operations in comparison with `add`/`remove`.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you understand the difference between LinkedList and ArrayList. ArrayList is implemented using Array.

LinkedList takes constant time to remove an element.
ArrayList might take linear time to remove the first element (to confirm I need to check the implementation, not java expert here).

Also I think LinkedList is more efficient in terms of space. Because ArrayList would not (and should not) re-size the array every time an element is removed, it takes up more space than needed.

Comment: `ArrayList` in Java is not double-ended so it needs to shift everything when you remove the first item. `ArrayList` is more space efficient than `LinkedList` for large lists though since a LinkedList uses 3 references for each item (value, next and previous) whereas an `ArrayList` only needs one reference per item plus unused space.

Comment: Don't forget the wrapper object takes up memory as well

Comment: @Raniz Thanks for adding the detail. Just to clarify, what I mean by "more efficient in terms of space" is that when an element is removed from linked-list, the list shrinks; in the case of ArrayList the ArrayList does not get resized after the deletion. Although trimToSize() helps.

Answer (score 5):

I think that what you need is an `ArrayDeque` (an unfairly overlooked class in `java.util`). Its `removeFirst` method performs in O(1) as for `LinkedList`, while it generally shows the better space and time characteristics of `ArrayList`. It’s implemented as a circular queue in an array.

You should very rarely use `LinkedList`. I did once in my 17 years as Java programmer and regretted in retrospect.

Comment: You can also use `List.subList(...)`, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46211629/480894

Comment: You can, @Roland. If both additions and removals go on, I cannot see how it will be practical, though. If the list is filled only once and after that only removed from, `subList()` should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

[List.subList​(int fromIndex, int toIndex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-)

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive.

Good to use for [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) where removing the first element has complexity O(n).

```
final String firstServerName = servers.get(0);
servers = servers.subList(1, servers.size());
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a linked list is by far faster.

**LinkedList**

It will just reference the nodes so the first one disappears.
[image]

**ArrayList**

With an Array List it has to move all elements back one spot to keep the underlying array proper.

Answer (score 3):

Removing the first element of an ArrayList is O(n). For the linked list is O(1), so I'll go with that.

Check the ArrayList [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

> The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run
>   in constant time. The add operation runs in amortized constant time,
>   that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. **All of the other
>   operations run in linear time (roughly speaking)**. The constant factor
>   is low compared to that for the LinkedList implementation.

This guys actually got the OpenJDK source [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24462605/376382)

Comment: O(n)? Either it's a typo or my understanding of list.remove(0) is not correct. Can you please explain how it's O(n)?

Comment: @prabugp it's not a typo

Comment: @prabugp Elements after it have to be shifted.

Answer (score 3):

As others have rightly pointed out, LinkedList is faster than ArrayList for removal of the first element from anything other than a very short list.

However, to make your choice between them you need to consider the complete mix of operations. For example, if your workload does millions of indexed accesses to a hundred element list for each first element removal, ArrayList will be better overall.

Answer (score 2):

**Third Aproach.**

It is exposed by the java.util.Queue interface. LinkedList is an implementation of this interface.

The Queue interface is exposing  the  E poll() method which effectively removes the head of the List (Queue).

In terms of performance the poll() method is comparable to removeFirst(). Actually it is using under the hood the removeFirst() method.